# How to get PHP "setrawcookie" value back?

Tags: php, http, cookies, cgi

The IETF recommends using base64 encoding for binary cookie values:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpstate-cookie-07

So I use `setrawcookie(..)` but I don't know what variable to use to get the cookie back because `$_COOKIE[..]` still uses the URL decoding that matches `setcookie(..)`. This replaces "+" with " " in the output.

```
<?php

var_dump($_COOKIE['TEST']);
$binary_string = "";
for($index = 0; $index < 256; $index++){
    $binary_string .= chr($index);
}
$encoded_data = base64_encode($binary_string);
var_dump($encoded_data);
$cookie_set = setrawcookie('TEST', $encoded_data, time() + 3600);
?>
```

Comment: are you sure your cookie is set properly? You're using `var_dump` that output some data, and after this cookie can not be set so you may be operating on some old cookie?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use normal **`setcookie`** instead `setrawcookie`, this way you can avoid situation when trying to send cookie with not allowed characters (cookie will not be set) and it's value in `$_COOKIE` array will be usable.

If you insist on raw method, you can find cookies send by browser in **`$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']`**. This will be string formatted like `key1=value1; key2=value2`. One way to get it in array is to do simple exploding:

```
foreach(explode('; ',$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']) as $rawcookie)
{
    list($k,$v) = explode('=',$rawcookie, 2);
    $_RAWCOOKIE[$k] = $v;
}

var_dump($_RAWCOOKIE);
```